# Azure SQL Database free with Azure free account

Tags: azure

I tried the Microsoft tutorial [from here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/free-sql-db-free-account-how-to-deploy?view=azuresql) to create Azure SQL Database free with Azure free account. But after I follow until step 10,

[image]

I can see that there is a Estimated Cost in my screen. Am I doing it correctly?

[image]

> Using an Azure free account, you can try Azure SQL Database for free
> for 12 months with the following monthly limit:
>
> 1 S0 database with 10 database transaction units and 250 GB storage

Comment: The main problem with this "free" tiers, both AWS and Azure, is that you must be always checking if you shut on/off your services, and if you fail one day, or if you are sleeping, on holiday, travelling, if your latpot just gets out of battery... A simple DDOS attack or the fact of reaching the limit just in the moment can generate for you costs for +400$ in a few days. Microsoft and AWS support must be really tired of checking tickets about that undesired costs, defaults, etc, etc, you ALWAYS are suitable for getting charges, the name "free" is a false friend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Those are the compute costs

As per this [MSDocs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/purchasing-models?view=azuresql#dtu-purchasing-model),

- In the DTU-based purchasing approach, expenses are computed and bundled using database transaction units (DTUs).
- You are charged according to the quantity of DTUs you allot to your database for your application.